# Find an absotule convergent series that is not convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

find the sequence of polynomials $(P_n)$ such that $\sum P_n$ converges absolutely (that is $\sum \|P_n\|_{\infty}\lt\infty $) but is not convergent in the space ($\mathcal{P}[0,1], \|.\|_{\infty}$, i.e. sup norm)

i thought of the taylor series of cosx, $e^x$ etc. the $(P_n)$ is not convergent in the space of polynomials but are they absolutely convergent to a polynomial?

could you please give some insight

Comment: Go for an approximation of a characteristic function, for example.

Comment: for characteristic function, dirichlet function comes to my mind. so to  a sequence of polynomials in absolute value will be constant function. am i in a correct direction?

Comment: You should add "uniformly" to the title of the question. Otherwise it is very confusing.

Comment: edited the question. hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$, in which case
$$
P_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^n\,\frac{x^n}{n}.
$$

Comment: here, isn't $\|P_n\|_{\infty}=1/n$, so $\sum\frac{1}{n}=\infty$

Comment: You have changed the question. The word "absolutely" changes everything. In fact what you ask now is impossible. If $\sum\|P_n\|_\infty<\infty$, then by the Weierstrass $M$-test the series converges uniformly. My example answers the original question: uniformly convergent but not absolutely convergent on $[0,1]$.